# Display guest details who paid total charges RS.50000 and above. Write a query to fetch Guest id, Guest name and Sum of total charges

Tags: sql, database, group-by, sum, having-clause

```
   GUESTID NAME               TOTALCHARGE
---------- ------------------------------ -----------
      1234 RAJ GUPTA                30000
      1235 JACK MARTIN              30000
      1236 MARY GREY                32000
      1234 RAJ GUPTA                30000
      1235 JACK MARTIN              48000
```

Comment: I hope that's not all the data, because none of the `TOTALCHARGE` values are 50000 or over...

Comment: The title of your question should contain an abstract of what you are asking. The actual (complete) question should be part your question's body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an aggregate query with filtering:

```
select guestid, name, sum(totalcharge) sum_totalcharge
from mytable
group by guestid, name
having sum(totalcharge) >= 50000
```